# How to copy multiple table with header from Excel to Ms. Word with Macro?

Tags: vba, excel

i have this code to copy excel table and give header for each table to Ms. Word

```
Sub RoundedRectangle2_Click()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object
Dim OrderNo As Long
Dim OrderNo2 As Long
Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
Dim strValue As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set WrkSht = Sheet1
Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add
wdApp.Visible = True

WrkSht.Activate
OrderNo = 1
For OrderNo2 = OrderNo To 16
    OrderNo = Cells(OrderNo2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Set Rng = ActiveCell.Range("A" & OrderNo2 & ":C" & OrderNo)
    strValue = Cells(OrderNo2 + 1, 1)

    Rng.Copy
    With wd.Range
    wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=strValue
        .Collapse Direction:=0
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .Collapse Direction:=0
        .PasteSpecial False, False, True
    End With
    wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

    OrderNo2 = OrderNo + 1
Next
End Sub
```

for example i have below table on excel

```
product | sub_porduct | price |
A       |    1231     |   6   |
A       |    3331     |   5   |
A       |    1233     |   9   |

product | sub_porduct | price |
B       |    1299     |   10  |
B       |    1001     |   9   |

product | sub_porduct | price |
C       |    1871     |  15   |
C       |    1854     |  17   |
C       |    1782     |  19   |
C       |    1771     |  18   |
```

The problem is wherever i put TypeText, they always write on Ms. Word as below.

```
A
B
C

product | sub_porduct | price |
A       |    1231     |   6   |
A       |    3331     |   5   |
A       |    1233     |   9   |

product | sub_porduct | price |
B       |    1299     |   10  |
B       |    1001     |   9   |

product | sub_porduct | price |
C       |    1871     |  15   |
C       |    1854     |  17   |
C       |    1782     |  19   |
C       |    1771     |  18   |
```

my expected is header write before each table and give format header1 for each header like below on ms. Word

```
A
product | sub_porduct | price |
A       |    1231     |   6   |
A       |    3331     |   5   |
A       |    1233     |   9   |

B
product | sub_porduct | price |
B       |    1299     |   10  |
B       |    1001     |   9   |

C
product | sub_porduct | price |
C       |    1871     |  15   |
C       |    1854     |  17   |
C       |    1782     |  19   |
C       |    1771     |  18   |
```

Please help to fix the code. Thx a lot for any help

Comment: The header **is** there before **each** table. I don't see what you are missing. On another note though, your variable `OrderNo` and `OrderNo2` are pretty chaotic. You are changing the upperbound of the for loop inside the for loop... what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Hi, i want to generate in doc  with order header A then(new line) table A below it, (new line) header B (new line) then table B and so on. But the result is header A, header B, header C then table A, table B, table C. i use OrderNo and OrderNo2 because i want create cursor range to select each table, so it will not repeat cursor in each row. therefore i jump to last row for each table (var OrderNo+1).